Pasting to a Worksheet based on Cell Value
I'm trying to separate specific data from a Master list into individual sheets. Having trouble specifying the destination sheet based on a cell value from the master list.
Sub TESTT()
    Dim wss As Sheets
    Dim ws As Worksheet, master As Worksheet
    
    Set master = Worksheets("FMASTER")
    Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set ws = wss(master.Cells(2, 3).Value) 'Cell C2 Value

    master.Range("A2").Copy
    ws.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")

End Sub


This was just a small test. Once I had it working, I would then put it in a function that would loop through all rows, target the specific sheet and copy/paste a few cells from that row.

what error? What line? When? No info enough.  Anyways, looking at your code you should deeply revise how VBA works.

I think you are missing a ws reference in the final line i.e. ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Range("A1")

I get a "Subscript out of Range" Error for trying to reference the cell value in the master sheet as the worksheet name master.Cells(2, 3).Value

Assuming that a worksheet with the name of cell C3 of your worksheet exists, setting the destination worksheet will work (you don't need the wss-variable, btw).
The problem with your code is the copy+paste operation. The line
ws.Paste Destination:=Range("A1") 

will not do what you expect. Destination:=Range("A1") will not copy into range A1 of the worksheet ws, it will copy into Range A1 of the current active sheet. You always need to specify the sheet, else VBA will assume the active sheet. This, for example, will do the trick:
ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Range("A1") 

If you only want to copy the content of cells, not the formatting, the following statements are much more efficient (all do the same):
ws.Range("A1").Value = master.Range("A2").Value
ws.Range("A1") = master.Range("A2")
ws.Cells(1, 1) = master.Cells(2, 1)


Many thanks, I don't require the formatting so that is very handy. I am getting a debug error on the line to "Set ws =" though.

That likely means that Cell C2 of the sheet FMASTER does not contain a sheet name that already exists. Check the content of the cell - especially if it contains leading or trailing blanks.

Seems it didn't like the format of the cells, even though I changed them all to text. Went through and redone them, working a treat now. Many thanks.


Seems it didn't like the format of the cells

No, you're wrong, that's not the problem.
You have a value written in cell C2 on the FMASTER sheet, this is the name of the sheet, or you have a drop-down list with the names of the sheets in the workbook. Depending on this (C2) value, data from cell A2 of the FMASTER sheet is inserted onto that sheet.
Option Explicit

Sub TESTT()
    '    Dim wss         As Sheets   '1) ???
    '    Dim ws          As Worksheet    '2) ???
    Dim master As Worksheet, wss As Worksheet
    Dim ws          As String

    Set master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FMASTER")
    '    Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets   '1) ???
    '    Set ws = wss(master.Cells(2, 3).Value)   '2) ???   ' Cell C2 Value
    ws = master.Cells(2, 3).Value
    Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws)

    master.Range("A2").Copy
    '    ws.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")   ' ???
    wss.Paste Destination:=wss.Range("A1")

    '    ' Or
    '    wss.Range("A1").Value = master.Range("A2").Value
    '    wss.Range("A1") = master.Range("A2")
    '    wss.Cells(1, 1) = master.Cells(2, 1)

    wss.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set wss = Nothing
    Set master = Nothing
End Sub

Maybe I'm wrong. Good luck.
